# UnitConverter action problems

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, events

I have three ComboBoxes on my form. What is the event so that if an item in Combobox1 is selected, the options in ComboBox2 and ComboBox3 change.

Comment: Mohit, are you doing this in WInforms or WPF?

Comment: Sorry. I'm doing it in Winforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the OnChange event, when that occurs you can modify the other comboboxes as needed.

I dont really have a good answer for your other question, sorry.